# How to Build String from a Collection of Names

Tags: c#, string

I have a collection of first names which I need to combine into a comma separated string.

The generated string needs to adhere to proper grammar.

If the collection contains one name, then the output should be just that name:

```
John
```

If the collection contains two names, then the output should be separated by the word "and":

```
John and Mary
```

If the collection contains three or more names, then the output should be comma delimited, and the last name should have the word "and" before it:

```
John, Mary, and Jane
```

Here is the code I came up with.  Its not very elegant and I'd like to know if there is a better way to accomplish this in C# (4.0 is OK).

```
List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();
firstNames.Add("John");
firstNames.Add("Mary");
firstNames.Add("Jane");

string names = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < firstNames.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 1 && firstNames.Count == 2)
    {
        names += " and ";
    }
    else if (firstNames.Count > 2 && i > 0 && i != firstNames.Count - 1)
    {
        names += ", ";
    }
    else if (i != 0 && i == firstNames.Count - 1)
    {
        names += ", and ";
    }

    names += firstNames[i];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `, and` between the last two?

Comment: @Henk, That is a matter of preference. Both (with and without the comma) are correct.

Comment: Style guides usually add the comma, but they also (sometimes) state that you can dispense with it. ie. both "A, B and C" and "A, B, and C" are considered correct, but the latter is the one most often suggested. See http://www.wikihow.com/Use-English-Punctuation-Correctly for one such example, section 5, second bullet-point.

Comment: It's grammatically correct to have that last comma in there.  Vampire Weekend has a song about it.

Comment: But not strictly necessary, "and" is also considered to connect the series. In other words, you're not breaking any rules if you drop it, but typical suggestions are to add it. In any case, this is a bikeshed problem :)

Comment: Right, I think I could probably go either way with the last ", and", but the particular requirement I'm working on specifies having the comma in there.

Comment: Oxford comma. I personally prefer it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it will get more elegant than:

```
 if (names.Count == 0)
     return "";

 if (names.Count == 1)
     return names[0];

 if (names.Count == 2)
     return names[0] + " and " + names[1];

 return String.Join(", ", names.Take(names.Count - 1)) +
     ", and "  + names[names.Count - 1];
```

I haven't compiled this, but I think you get the idea.

EDIT: Shorter, but less readable:

```
 if (names.Count <= 2)
     return String.Join(" and ", names);

 return String.Join(", ", names.Take(names.Count - 1)) + 
     ", and "  + names[names.Count - 1];
```

Comment: +1 I'm often surprised about how few programmers know about `Join()`

Comment: I didn't.  Even though this is a trivial problem, I've learned something that will be useful for future problems too!

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();
        firstNames.Add("John");
        firstNames.Add("Mary");
        firstNames.Add("Jane");
        Console.WriteLine(NamesString(firstNames));
    }

    static string NamesString(List<string> firstNames) {
        switch (firstNames.Count) {
        case 0:
            return string.Empty;
        case 1:
            return firstNames[0];
        case 2:
            return string.Join(" and ", firstNames.ToArray());
        default:
            return string.Format("{0} and {1}",
                string.Join(", ", firstNames.ToArray(), 0, firstNames.Count - 1),
                firstNames[firstNames.Count - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: actually should be

```
        default:
            return string.Format("{0}, and {1}",
```

if you want a comma before the last "and".

Answer (score 2):

```
        string a=string.Join(",", FirstNames.ToArray());
        if (FirstNames.Count == 1)
            a.Replace(",", "");
        else if (FirstNames.Count == 2)
            a.Replace(",", " and ");
        else
        {
            int i = a.LastIndexOf(",");
            a = a.Substring(1, i) + a.Substring(i).Replace(",", " and ");
        }
```

Comment: This solution does not take into account the need for the last name to have "and" inserted before it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    static string JoinNames(List<string> firstNames)
    {
        int count = firstNames.Count;
        if(count == 1)
        {
            return firstNames[0];
        }

        if(count > 1)
        {
            return string.Join(", ", firstNames.Take(count - 1).ToArray()) + " and " + firstNames[count - 1];
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();
firstNames.Add("John");
firstNames.Add("Mary");
firstNames.Add("Jane");

StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < firstNames.Count; i++)
{
    if((i-1) == firstNames.Count && names.length > 0)
         names.AppendFormat(" and {0}", names[i]);
    else if(names.length > 0)
         names.AppendFormat(", {0}", names[i]);    
}
return names.ToString();
```

I think this is the best way.

Comment: won't you get a comma appended if the list only contains one name? you also confuse the use of names and firstNames?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();
firstNames.Add("John");
firstNames.Add("Mary");
firstNames.Add("Jane");
int cnt = 0;
string names = string.Empty;
while (cnt<=firstName.Count)
{
    string separator = "";

    if (firstName.Count - cnt > 1) separator = ", ";

    else if (firstName.Count - cnt = 1) separator = ", and ";

    else separator = "";

    names += firstName[cnt] + separator;

    cnt += 1;


}
```

Comment: I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException when the input list only contains one name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting solution:

```
        //code
        List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();
        firstNames.Add("John");
        firstNames.Add("Mary");
        firstNames.Add("Jane");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        firstNames.Take(firstNames.Count - 1).ToList().ForEach(fn => AddString(fn, sb));
        sb.Append(", and " + firstNames.Last());

    //Helper Function
    public void AddString (string fn, StringBuilder sb)
    {
        if (sb.Length != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(", ");
        }
        sb.Append(fn);
    }
```

Comment: When there is only one input name, this prints:
', and John'

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
            List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();
            firstNames.Add("John");
            firstNames.Add("Mary");
            firstNames.Add("Jane");

            // Only do this if there is more than one name
            if (firstNames.Count > 1)
            {
                string separator = ", ";

                // Join the names, using ", " as a separator
                string names = String.Join(seperator, firstNames.ToArray());

                // Insert "and" before the last comma
                names = names.Insert(names.LastIndexOf(separator), ", and ");

                // Remove the last comma
                names = names.Remove(names.LastIndexOf(separator), separator.Length);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = String.Join(", ", firstNames.Skip(1).ToArray()) + (firstNames.Count < 2 ? "" : ", and ") + firstNames.Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This solution inserts a comma when there are only two names in the collection.

Comment: ah ok. What an idiot I am, thanks for pointing that out. That's what happens when you bung the comma in at the last minute.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the code that is the most readable. You have 4 punctuation cases to consider when adding a name to a list, so just spell them out.

```
static string Combine(List<string> names)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) //at start of a list
            {}

        else if (i < names.Count - 1) //in middle of list
            sb.Append(", ");

        else if( names.Count == 2 ) //at end of a list with 2 elements
            sb.Append(" and ");

        else //at end of a list with 3 or more elements
            sb.Append(", and ");

        sb.Append(names[i]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string Combine(List<string> names)
{
    if (names == null || names.Count == 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(names[0]);

    //Handle Special Case of 2 names
    if (names.Count == 2)
    {
        sb.Append(" and " + names[1])
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < names.Count; i++)          
    {
        if (i == (names.Count -1))
        { 
            sb.Append(", and " + names[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(", " + names[i]);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString(); 
}
```